# CASE - sythax error near unexpected token

Tags: bash, syntax-error, case, linux-mint

I have problem while running quite large script. In the middle output says:

```
linuxMint_post-install.sh: line 131: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
linuxMint_post-install.sh: line 131: `    "1") echo -e "\e[0;32m you have hdd, skipping to the next step... \e[0m" ;;'
```

I don't want you make this to lonng (script counts 260 lines) so I will post only related part:

```
echo -e "\e[0;32m First we will check if you have ssd or hdd drive \e[0m"
ssd_check="$( cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational )"
case "$ssd_check" in
    "0") echo -e "\e[0;32m you have ssd drive, so we will optimaze that \e[0m" ;
         # noatime
         #TODO add noatime automaticly with sed, use code bellow for check (look at I/O scheduler as example)
         echo -e "\e[0;32m fstab file will open in xed text editor. Add \"noatime,\" right before \"errors=remount-ro 0 1\" \e[0m" ;
         echo -e "\e[0;32m This line has to look like this: \e[0m" ;
         echo -e "\e[0;32m UUID=xxxxxxx / ext4 noatime,errors=remount-ro 0 1 \e[0m" ;
         echo -e "\e[0;32m When you finish, save file, close text editor and continue \e[0m" ;
         gksudo xed /etc/fstab ;
         read -n1 -r -p "Press any key to continue..." key ;
         # trimming
         echo -e "\e[0;32m Now we will change trimming from weekly to daily schedule in cron \e[0m" ;
         sudo mv -v /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim /etc/cron.daily ; # if you want to undo this operation simply: sudo mv -v /etc/cron.daily/fstrim /etc/cron.weekly
         # swap limit
         echo -e "\e[0;32m Now we will chaeck if the swap limit is set to correct value for not overusing SSD \e[0m"
         swap_check="$( head -1 /proc/sys/vm/swappiness )"
         if [ "$swap_check" -gt 1 ]; then
              #MANUAL VERSION v
              echo -e "\e[0;32m Swap limit is set to "$swap_check" which is to high. We have to reduce it to 1 \e[0m" 
              echo -e "\e[0;32m To do so, we will open /proc/sys/vm/swappiness file and please write those two lines at the end of this file: \e[0m"
              echo -e "\e[0;32m # Sharply reduce the inclination to swap \e[0m"
              echo -e "\e[0;32m vm.swappiness=1 \e[0m"
              gksudo xed /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
              echo -e "\e[0;32m When you finish, save file, close text editor and continue \e[0m"
              read -n1 -r -p "Press any key to continue..." key ;
              #AUTOMATIC version - not working! v            
              #sudo echo "# Sharply reduce the inclination to swap" >> /proc/sys/vm/swappiness  #add this lines to reduce swap
              #sudo echo "vm.swappiness=1" >> /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
              #TODO ^ sudo echo doesn't work, I have tried with command: echo "some text here" | sudo tee -a /proc/.../swappiness with no success to

         else
              :
         fi
         # disable hibernation https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/bugs#TOC-Hibernate-and-suspend-don-t-always-work-well:-they-make-some-computers-malfunction-or-even-enter-a-coma
         echo -e "\e[0;32m this step will disable hibernation which will reduce hdd usage, you will be still able to use \"suspend\", \e[0m" 
         echo -e "\e[0;32m it takes more energy in compare to \"hibernate \", but saves your ssd. You can olways undo this operation later or skip this step \e[0m"
         echo -e "\e[0;32m would you like to procede? [y/n] \e[0m"
         while read y_n; do
             case "$y_n" in
              [Yy]* ) sudo mv -v /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla / # com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla will be moved to / to undo simply move it back again to /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/
                      echo -e "\e[0;32m hibernation disabled \e[0m" ;;                                                                              
              [Nn]* ) echo -e "\e[0;32m hibernation remains enabled \e[0m";; 
                   *) echo -e "\e[0;31m Wrong input! Type y or n \e[0m" ;        
             esac
         done
         # I/O scheduler setting to deadline http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-change-the-linux-io-scheduler-to-fit-your-needs/
         echo -e "\e[0;32m First we will check if I/O is already set to \"deadline\" \e[0m"
         IO_check="$ ( cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler )" #TODO Make some kind of check if linux is realy installed on sda
         case "$IO_check" in
            *[deadline]* ) echo -e "\e[0;32m I/O scheduler is already set to \"deadline\", moving to the next step \e[0m";;
                        *) sudo sed -i 's/\quiet splash\b/& elevator=deadline/' /etc/default/grub ;
                           sudo update-grub ;
                           IO_check="$ ( cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler )" #Checking if operation ended propperly
                           case "$IO_check" in
                              *[deadline]* ) echo -e "\e[0;32m I/O scheduler has been successfully set to \"deadline\", moving to the next step \e[0m";;
                                          *) echo -e "\e[0;32m I/O something went wrong, please add manually \"elevator=deadline\" right after \"quiet splash\" \e[0m";
                                             echo -e "\e[0;32m It has to look like this: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=\"quiet splash elevator=deadline\" \e[0m";
                                             gksudo xed /etc/default/grub ;
                                             echo "When you finish, save file, close text editor and continue" ;
                                             read -n1 -r -p "Press any key to continue..." key ;;
                           esac
         esac
    "1") echo -e "\e[0;32m you have hdd, skipping to the next step... \e[0m" ;;
      *) echo echo -e "\e[0;31m ERROR!!! Wrong output from disc type check \e[0m" ;
esac
```

Output says It is something related to my main case. I can't figure out what's wrong with that. I have tried "0") and "1") without quotes and also in brackets, but I got the same error.

Please help!

Comment: Please see the documentation on building a [mcve]. Code samples should be the **shortest possible code** tested to generate a given problem. If you can remove anything and the problem still exists, it should be removed *before asking the question*.

Comment: (You might also consider making sure that your code runs clean in http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here).

Comment: Mysterious syntax errors almost *always* occur before the line flagged by the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
"1") echo -e "\e[0;32m you have hdd, skipping to the next step... \e[0m" ;;
```

by

```
     ;;
"1") echo -e "\e[0;32m you have hdd, skipping to the next step... \e[0m" ;;
```

to close your first block with `"0")`.